# mysql command line append database

Tags: mysql, command, line

Would it be possible to append another sql into existing table data using a command like the one below.

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql
```

This command will overwrite the existing table data.

Looking at appending to existing instead of overwrite.

Any command for this ?

Comment: This will execute whatever is contained in your data.sql (just like as if you would execute these statements from wherever you normally do that). If the data.sql-file contains a command to drop and recreate a table and its data, it will do it. (That is often the case when you do a backup). If it would e.g. just contain inserts, it will append the data.

Comment: using this style of command from command prompt,  any way to do as you have mentioned ? any switches for this type of command ?
 

mysqldump --user=xxxxxx --password=xxxxxx  xxxxxx zzzzzz > aaaaaaa.sql

Comment: `mysqldump --no-create-info` might do what you want. But it will not (on import) check what data is already there; it expects an empty database, and it may or may not work correctly if there is data already. You may have to build a custom import script (that e.g. compares data or adjusts the sql file before import) if you have a more complicated requirement (and the bar for "complicated" is pretty low, as already something as "complicated" as having autoincrement ids might not automatically work as you hope it would)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the sql file that you want to add to existing data. It is likely a dump that includes the lines starting like this: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and/or it contains `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_name`

You need to remove these lines from the sql file that you feed into mysql, either by modifying the dump command with which you created the file (see --skip-add-drop-table option and --no-create-db options) or by removing those lines from the sql file with an editor or awk or something.

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

other relevant SO-links: [mysqldump with create database line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452523/mysqldump-with-create-database-line) and [MySQL import - How to ignore Drop table if exists line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573778/mysql-import-how-to-ignore-drop-table-if-exists-line)

Comment: i am trying to write an automated batch process using  

mysqldump --user=xxxxxx --password=xxxxxx  xxxxxx zzzzzz > aaaaaaa.sql

Comment: Interesting. I suggest reading up on the command line options of mysql-dump so that you only export what you need.